# need suggestion for writing procedure

Tags: mysql, database, select, stored-procedures, database-administration

actually I am writing procedure to get user from the table. The procedure looks like this

```
    DELIMITER $$
    CREATE PROCEDURE CheckUserDisable 
    (
    usertodisable varchar(64)
    ) 
    BEGIN 
    select str_id, email1, email2 from CI_CONTACTS c where c.str_id=usertodisable or (c.email1 in ("usertodisable@yyy.com", "usertodisable@xxx.com", "usertodisable@xyz.com")) or (c.email2 in ("usertodisable@yyyyy.com", "usertodis
able@xxxxx.com", "usertodisable@abc.com"));
END $$
```

Here I am trying to get user which I pass in parameters.

But it works for **c.str_id=usertodisable** condition and not for email condition

for example if I have str_id is **abc_25** and email like **abc@xxx.com**.
when I am calling procedure call CheckUserDisable('abc');

it won't return any result but it should display value **abc@xxx.com**

any suggestion for this?

Answer (score 2):

Double quotes are used to create string literals. So `"usertodisable@xxx.com"` is interpreted as a literal string `usertodisable@xxx.com`. You can use a `concat` function to combine a variable and a string to form a new string .

```
select str_id, email1, email2 from CI_CONTACTS c 
where c.str_id=usertodisable 
or (c.email1 in (concat(usertodisable,"@yyy.com"), concat(usertodisable,"@xxx.com"),concat(usertodisable,"@xyz.com")) 
or (c.email2 in (concat(usertodisable,"@yyyyy.com"), concat(usertodisable,"@xxxxx.com"), concat(usertodisable,"@abc.com"));
```

Comment: ok let me try this.thanks for help

Comment: *Double quotes are used to create string literals.* In MySQL - allowed, but not recommended. By 2 reasons. First one - they are used for JSON paths/values primarily. Second one - if ANSI_QUOTES server SQL mode is enabled then the value in dqchars will be treated as object (table, column, etc.) name. So use only single quote chars for literals.